# useSelector no funciona

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Estoy usando hoooks para conectar redux con react, pero por alguna razón no toma las propiedades de estado inicial como válidas. Aquí está mi código. Al intentar renderizar, me indica que .countryDetails es undefined. No tengo idea de qué está fallando.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

//Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getDetail } from '../actions/index';

const CountryDetails = ({match}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const countryById = useSelector(state => state.countryDetail);

    const {name} = countryById

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getDetail(match.params.id));
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default CountryDetails;
```

Mi reducer y mi estado inicial están hechos de la siguiente manera, no tengo ni idea de dónde está el error, porque mi primera acción SHOW_COUNTRIES funciona correctamente en su respectivo componente, pero intento usar cualquier otra propiedad de mi estado inicial y no funciona:

```
const initialState = {
    countries: [],
    filterCountries: [],
    countryDetail: [],
    activities: [],
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SHOW_COUNTRIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                filterCountries: action.payload,
                countries: action.payload,
            }
            case GET_COUNTRY:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    filterCountries: action.payload
                }
            case ORDER_AZ: 
                return {
                    ...state,
                    filterCountries: action.payload
                }
            case ORDER_ZA:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    filterCountries: action.payload
                }
            case ORDER_POP_MAJ:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    filterCountries: action.payload
                }
            case ORDER_POP_MIN:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    filterCountries: action.payload
                }
            case GET_DETAIL:
                console.log("reducer")
                return {
                    ...state,
                    countryDetail: action.payload
                }
```

Comment: Cómo se llena ese `countryDetail`?

Comment: parece ser un error de sintaxis debes tener mal escrito el state, podrias mostrar el initial state de redux ?

Comment: Ya lo edité en la publicación original para que sea más sencillo verlo.

Comment: estoy teniendo EXACTAMENTE el mismo problema en un proyecto, pudiste solucionarlo??